# Update Hidden List Field on jQuery UI Sortable?

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, lets say I am using the sortable function of jQuery UI with the following page:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    $( ".sortColumn" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortColumn",
        placeholder: "portlet-placeholder"
    });

    $( ".sortColumn" ).disableSelection();
});
</script> 

<form>
<table>
    <tr>

        <td class="sortColumn" id="left">
            <div class="portlet">
                This is Item 1
                <input type="hidden" name="modules[item1]" value="left">
            </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                This is Item 2
                <input type="hidden" name="modules[item2]" value="left">
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="sortColumn" id="right">
            <div class="portlet">
                This is Item 3
                <input type="hidden" name="modules[item3]" value="right">
            </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                This is Item 4
                <input type="hidden" name="modules[item4]" value="right">
            </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                This is Item 5
                <input type="hidden" name="modules[item5]" value="right">
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You will notice that each portlet has a hidden field that marks the position it is in (either "left" or "right"). As you can see, this is a portlet, so a user can drag and drop items from one column to another, and rearrange their order. As elements positions and orders are changed, I want those hidden fields to be updated to match the change. So if an item is moved from the right column to the left, it's position field should be changed to left.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortColumn" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortColumn",
        placeholder: "portlet-placeholder",
        update : function () { 
            $('input.position').each(function() {           
                var parentID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('ID');
                $(this).val( parentID );
            });
        }
    });

    $( ".sortColumn" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Also add a "position" class to the input fields.

```
<input class="position" type="hidden" name="modules[item1][position]" value="left">
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar, but I don't really understand what your update function is doing. Would you mind explaining it a little detail please? Thanks!

Comment: @Brian Fenton: to refer to the table cells (#left & #right), we use parent().parent(). $(this) refers to the input fields - and parentID is the id value of the cells. So: --- $(this).val( parentID ) ---